# Check if user is online

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Hello I want to update LastActive row every 10 seconds (something like a heartbeat), so I wrote this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var checkOn = setInterval(function()
    {
        $.get("cm/check-online.php");   
    }, 10000);
});

<?php
    require_once("config.php");

    $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

    $my_id = $_SESSION['z_id'];

    $q_update_myself = "UPDATE acc SET LastTimeActive='NOW()' AND LoggedIn='1' WHERE z_id='$my_id'";
    $do_q_update_myself = mysqli_query($dbc, $q_update_myself);
?>
```

but this doesn't work, and I don't know how to fix it :| I need this, because I use script to go throught all users, and if his LastTimeActive > 30, then it sets "LoggedIn" to 0.

And it doesn't work, because LastTimeActive is still same, as join_date... it doesnt change.

Comment: Define "doesn't work"

Comment: `LastTimeActive='NOW()'` --- do you realize you're assigning a string literal `'NOW()'` here?

Comment: is your script even called?

Comment: PHP has a time() function..what if it were placed instead of now

Comment: @user3251400: and if you put `echo 42;` in the very end of the script - will you see it as your ajax response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you check you are getting your Z_id session var from the PHP script AJAX is calling

You need do this on every page that accesses the session before you access it:

```
 session_start();
```

does this work for you?

```
<?php
require_once("config.php");
session_start();

$dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

$my_id = $_SESSION['z_id'];
$time_now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s")

if(isset($my_id) && !empty($my_id)){
$q_update_myself = "UPDATE acc SET LastTimeActive='$time_now' AND LoggedIn='1' WHERE z_id='$my_id'";
$do_q_update_myself = mysqli_query($dbc, $q_update_myself);
}else{
//error No Z_ID
}
?>
```

Comment: thank you, works... I had also to change my query, because "," was missing :)